Downcast with inherited operator=
Consider the following two classes:
struct Base {};

struct Derived : Base {
    using Base::Base;
    using Base::operator=;
};

In the answer to this question we learned about [over.match.funcs.general]#9, which applies to constructors, but not assignments:

[...] A constructor inherited from class type C ([class.inhctor.init]) that has a first parameter of type “reference to cv1 P” (including such a constructor instantiated from a template) is excluded from the set of candidate functions when constructing an object of type cv2 D if the argument list has exactly one argument and C is reference-related to P and P is reference-related to D.

In my understanding this is to prevent a downcast, i.e. the following must not (and does not) compile:
Base b;
Derived d = b;

But, you can circumvent this. Surprisingly, the following compiles (demo):
Base b;
Derived d;
d = b;

In using Base::operator=; the assignment operator seems to be treated as any other method Foo.
What is the rationale behind rejecting to downcast when constructing, but allowing it when assigning? I think, the quoted rule should also apply to assignments.

There are no casts, up or down, in your code. A cast is an explicit type conversion.

Some guesswork: d = b; cannot leave any member data uninitialized, but Derived d = b; could, in general.

@Caleth That's equally true about any inherited constructor, not just the copy constructor.

C++ wasn't born like Athena from the head of Zeus, grown-up and in full armour. It evolved.
using Base::operator= is C++98. At that time, people felt no need to exclude base class copy assignment. You want base class assignment operators, you get them, and nothing more. Is it slightly inconvenient that the copy assignment is brought into scope along with all the rest? Maybe, but only slightly. After all, operator= is just a regular function with a funny syntax. Why would the rules be different for it?
using Base::Base is C++11. Note that constructors, specifically one-argument constructors, are not just regular functions. Unlike assignment operators, they create implicit conversions and influence overload resolution and what not, and nobody wants inherited copy constructors to mess with that. Not even speaking about them just feeling wrong. So the relevant proposal specifically says that copy constructors are not inherited.
But wait a minute. Now that inheriting constructors is a thing, and inheriting copy constructors feels wrong, inheriting copy assignment operators also feels wrong! If inheriting assignment operators was a C++11 feature, perhaps it would be designed in sync with inheriting constructors. But it wasn't.
Of course C++11 would not invalidate perfectly working C++98 code just because of some tangentially related new feature, that would be sacrilegious. So the copy assignment is still inherited to this day.

So, you say inheriting copy assignment is bad indeed, but C++11 didn't want to change this, because it would break existing code bases? Is this all there is?

I can only guess.
